# Mock service of back end service to test proxy service of wso2 integrator

Tags: testing, wso2, soapui

I have created a proxy service in wso2. I need to create a mock service of back end service. Upon hitting the endpoint of proxy service, it should get processed by all mediators and proxy service should hit the endpoint of mock service and give the response. Please suggest  how it can be done in soapui ?

Answer (score 1):

Mocking a soap web service has nothing to do with wso2. you can do it via soapui (Assuming you need a soap mock service as backend). Go through soap [mock service documentation](https://www.soapui.org/docs/soap-mocking/service-mocking-overview/) and learn how to do it. It's not very complex as the provided documentation is detailed enough.
Once mock service is up and running, you can configure you wso2 proxy service with the mock endpoint, and invoke the proxy service.